# Login form validation with error messages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I'm trying to make a login form that check if my data are correct.

For example, if I insert a different value than "new_user" in the username field, then it should display a red error message under the submit button saying "please insert a valid user", and the border of the input field should be red as well.

If the username field is empty it has to do the same thing, just that the error message now has to be "please insert a username" and the same thing has to apply for the password field.

If the values for both username and password are matching has to display the message "Successfully Login"

I will attach an image just as an example, and I have added my code below. Please feel free to tell me what am I doing wrong.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var user = document.getElementById("username");
var pass = document.getElementById("password");
var botton = document.getElementById("btn")
var validUser = "new_user";
var validPassword = 123456789;

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkInputs();
})

user.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var username = user.value;
  if (username) {
    if (username === " " || username == null) {
      setErrorFor(user, "Please insert a username");
    } else if (username !== validUser) {
      setErrorFor(user, "Please insert a valid username");
    }
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(user, "Successfully Login")
  }
})

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
  var formControl = input.parentElement;
  var showError = document.querySelector(".text-message");
  var displayMessage = document.getElementById("msg");

  //add error message & add the class name inside the message element
  displayMessage.innerHTML = message
  showError.className = "text-message invalid"

  //add the error class
  formControl.classList = "form-control fail"
}

function setSuccessFor(input, message) {
  var formControl = input.parentElement;
  var showError = document.querySelector(".text-message");
  var displayMessage = document.getElementById("msg");

  //add error message & add the class name inside the message element
  displayMessage.innerHTML = message
  showError.className = "text-message valid"

  //add the error class
  formControl.classList = "form-control success"
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#login-container {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: .5em;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(88, 167, 236), rgb(180, 198, 214), rgb(180, 198, 214));
  padding: 3em 2.5em;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px #424241;
  text-align: justify;
}

.input-field {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: .5em 1.5em .5em .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
}

.form-control {
  position: relative;
}

.input-field i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.2em;
  right: .5em;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fa-check {
  color: green;
}

.fa-times {
  color: red;
}

form label {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
  background: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  border-radius: .5em;
  margin: 1em 0 .2em 0;
  padding: .5em 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
}

form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #70db70;
  color: white;
}

.text-message .msg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/*Message  classes*/

.form-control.success input {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.form-control.fail input {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check {
  opacity: 1;
}

.form-control.fail i.fa-times {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text-message.valid p {
  display: block;
  color: green;
}

.text-message.invalid p {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div class="input-field">
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input id="username" class="input" type="text">
      <i class="fas fa-check u_check"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-times u_decline"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" class="input" type="password">
      <i class="fas fa-check p_check"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-times p_decline"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn">
  <div class="text-message">
    <p id="msg" class="msg"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that a client-side authentication mechanism will never be secure. Not sure if it needs to be or if this is just a small project to learn some javascript, but I thought it would be worth noting.

Comment: It is just a project for the courses I take at the academy

Comment: Where is `checkInputs()` defined?